# If $H$ is a subloop of a finte loop $L$ and $N$ is a normal subloop of $L$, then $HN$ is a subloop of $L$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, associativity, quasigroups

To prove this is a subloop, I have to show that for $x, y \in HN$, the following are also in $HN$: (a) $xy$, (b) $L^{-1}_x(y)$ and (c) $R^{-1}_{x}(y)$.

Here $L_x(y) = xy$ and $R_x(y)=yx$. We have to show that inverses of these translation maps are in $HN$.

The first part (a) that the product is inside $HN$ is easy. I need help with both/one of the others.

Comment: What definition of "normal" are you using?  If you use $N$ is normal in $L$ if $aN=Na,a(bN)=(ab)N, (Nb)a=N(ba),$ and $a(Nb)=(aN)b$ for all $a,b\in L$, then the proof is similar as in groups.

Comment: @MarkGreer Yes that is the definition we're using. However, I've been asked to prove it is a subloop only. Proving it normal would be better, but I still have to prove it is a subloop first using the method outlined in the question. Doing so is a bit tricky to me because I'm a little new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof goes like:

(a): Let Let $x,y \in HN$. Say $x=h_1 n_1, y=h_2 n_2$. Then

$xy=(h_1 n_1)(h_2 n_2)$

$= h_1 (n_1' \cdot h_2 n_2)$ because $(aN)b=a(Nb)$

$= h_1 (n_1'' h_2 \cdot n_2)$ because $(Na)b=N(ab)$

$= h_1 (h_2 n_1''' \cdot n_2)$ because $aN=Na$

$= (h_1 \cdot h_2 n_1''') n_2'$ because $(aN)b=a(Nb)$

$= (h_1 h_2 \cdot n_1^{*}) n_2' $ because $b(aN)=(ba)N$

$=(h_1h_2)(n_1^{**}n_2')$ because $(aN)b=a(Nb)$

$\in HN$.

(b): Let $x,y \in HN$.

Let $L_x^{-1}(y)=u$,

$\implies y=L_x(u) = xu$,

$\implies h_2 n_2 = (h_1 n_1)u = h_1(n_1' u) = h_1(u n_1'') = (h_1 u)n_1'''$,

$\implies$ these cosets are equal: $h_2 N = (h_1 u)N$.

Now $h_2 \in h_2N = (h_1 u)N$,

$\implies h_2 = (h_1 u)n_0 = h_1 (u n_0') \in H$

$\implies  u n_0' \in H$ because $H$ is a subloop of $L$.

$\implies u n_0' = h \in hN,$

$\implies uN = hN,$

$\implies u \in uN = hN \subset HN$.

Hence $L_x^{-1}(y) \in HN$.

The proof for part (c) is similar to (b).